# Hypothesis testing example

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose we're looking at a two-candidate mayoral race in Providence. Candidate A is declared winner with 55 percent of the vote (p(hat) = 0.55). However, candidate B is suspicious of these results. Having his group of close friends take a random sample of 17 voters from Providence, he finds that 7 voted for candidate A while 10 voted for him.

On the basis of this study performed at the alpha = 0.05 level of significance, should candidate B demand a recount?

Formulate the null and alternative hypothesis and perform the test in order to respond to this question.

H0: u = 0.55

H1: u < 0.55 since p = 7/14 = 0.41

z = p(hat) - p / sqrt(p(1-p)/n) = 0.55 - 0.41 / sqrt(0.41(1-0.41)/17) = 1.17

p(z < 1.17) = 0.879 p(z > 1.17) = 1 - 0.879 = 0.123

Since 0.123 > 0.05, we don't reject the null hypothesis and candidate B shouldn't demand a recount.

Is this correct?

Comment: Finding out that you really lost by 4% instead of 5% wouldn't be worth much.  I would make the null hypothesis $u \ge 0.5$. and the alternative $u < 0.5$.

Comment: The rejection formula you used relies on approximation of a binomial distribution ($n=17$, $p=0.55$) to a normal distribution.  That is legible if $np(1-p)\geq10$ which is not satisfied in our case.  Hence you should apply the appropriate binomial distribution.